# Checkbox should be checked/unchecked based on database values using WPF-MVVM

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm, binding

I am working on WPF-MVVM ,I  have a user control  window  where in it contains      a  combo box and checkbox.
   The Combo values and Checkbox contents are dynamic.
   I have the problem in getting the values checked/unchhecked as per the combo         box change. 
 It is working properly if its a WPF window but not on User  control Window.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM_Ribbon.Views.UserModuleMappi"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_Ribbon.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:MVVM_Ribbon.ViewModel"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
    <VM:UserModuleMappingViewModel>
         </VM:UserModuleMappingViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>-->
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label FontSize="17" Content="User Id:" Margin="30,10,187,203" RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,1.597" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label FontSize="15" Grid.Column="0" Content="Modules:"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,1.597" Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,56,187,150"/>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbuserId" Height="25" Width="120" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxItems}" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="123,16,49,0"/>

    <ListBox Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding checkboxItems }" Margin="127,65,53,92" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox  Name="checkModules" Content="{Binding}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Command="{Binding CheckCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  />

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Margin="1"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

```
   Model.cs

    namespace MVVM_Ribbon.Model
   {
      class UserModuleMapping : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
    private ObservableCollection<string> _listData;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListData
    {
        get { return _listData; }
        set { _listData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ListData"); }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<string> GetListData()
    {
        ListData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string qry = "";
            qry = "select User_Id,EMP_Name from User_Id";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            sa.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string UserId = dt.Rows[i]["User_Id"].ToString();
                ListData.Add(UserId);
            }


            return ListData;
        }
    }

    //---------------------------for checkbox generation

    private ObservableCollection<string> _modulesData;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ModulesData
    {
        get { return _modulesData; }
        set { _modulesData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ModulesData"); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> getModules()
    {
        ModulesData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string qry = "";
            qry = "select * from [dbo].[Module_Mstr]";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            sa.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string mod_name = dt.Rows[i]["Module_Name"].ToString();
                ModulesData.Add(mod_name);
            }
            return ModulesData;
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<string> _userModule;

    public ObservableCollection<string> UserModule
    {
        get { return _userModule; }
        set { _userModule = value; OnPropertyChanged("UserModule"); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> getuserModules(string user_id)
    {
        UserModule = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string qry = "";
            qry = " select umap.User_Id,umap.Module_Id,mod_mstr.Module_Name " +
                  " from[dbo].[UserModule_Map] umap,Module_Mstr mod_mstr where" +
                  " umap.Module_Id = mod_mstr.Module_Id and umap.User_Id = '" + user_id + "'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sa.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string user_mod_name = dt.Rows[i]["Module_Name"].ToString();
                UserModule.Add(user_mod_name);
            }
            return UserModule;

        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    //--------------------end-------------------------------

}}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
     class UserModuleMappingViewModel : ModelBase
{
    string user_Id;

    public CollectionView comboBoxItems { get; set; }
    public CollectionView checkboxItems { get; set; }
    public bool Loaded { get; set; }
    public ICommand GetData { get; set; }
    public ICommand GetMod { get; set; }


    private bool isChecked;
    private ICommand checkCommand;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public ICommand OnCheckedCommand
    {
        get
        {

            return checkCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            checkCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OnCheckedCommand");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _listData;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListData
    {
        get { return _listData; }
        set { _listData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ListData"); }

    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _modulesData;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ModulesData
    {
        get { return _modulesData; }
        set { _modulesData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ModulesData"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _userModules;
    public ObservableCollection<string> UserModules
    {
        get { return _userModules; }
        set { _userModules = value; OnPropertyChanged("UserModules"); }
    }
    public UserModuleMappingViewModel()
    {
        GetListData();
        GetModulesData();
        //GetUserModules();
        GetData = new RelayCommand(GetItemsData);
        GetMod = new RelayCommand(GetModules);
        IsChecked = true;
    }
    private void GetItemsData(object obj)
    {
        var Item = comboBoxItems.CurrentItem;
        MessageBox.Show(Item.ToString());
    }
    private void GetModules(object obj)
    {
        var modul = checkboxItems.CurrentItem;
        MessageBox.Show(modul.ToString());
    }
    private void GetListData()
    {
        ListData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        ListData = model.GetListData();
        comboBoxItems = new CollectionView(model.GetListData());
        comboBoxItems.MoveCurrentTo(ListData[0]);
        comboBoxItems.CurrentChanged += ComboBoxItems_CurrentChanged;
    }
    private void GetModulesData()
    {
        ModulesData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        ModulesData = model.getModules();
        checkboxItems = new CollectionView(model.getModules());
        checkboxItems.MoveCurrentTo(ModulesData[0]);
    }

    private void GetUserModules()
    {
        UserModules = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        UserModules = model.getuserModules(user_Id);
        //checkboxItems = new CollectionView(model.getuserModules(user_Id));
        //checkboxItems.MoveCurrentTo(UserModules[0]);
    }

    private void ComboBoxItems_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Loaded)
        {
            user_Id = ((CollectionView)sender).CurrentItem.ToString();
            GetUserModules();

        }
        Loaded = true;
    }
    public void ShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
    }



}
```

Comment: post code of what you have done so far.

Comment: Please add some code so that we can see how you are implementing that. However, If you have set the correct DataContext, you can bind the IsChecked property of the checkbox to a boolean in your viewmodel that implement INoifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I know you are just learning but.... that is one ugly viewmodel. A CollectionView is a **view** related construct (it helps you order items in the UI). You should also resist having property names like *comboboxItems* - keeping it clean of any sort of UI contamination (even if it's just a name) leads to a proper separation of concerns. Also don't have ObservableCollections in your model - you shouldn't be observing anything in that layer.

Comment: I agree with @slugster Once i am done learning i will seperate it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong command set to your CheckBox since you are binding to CheckCommand but you have  OnCheckedCommand in your ViewModel. Also , if you want to use a command, you can get rid of IsChecked property and do the following

```
<CheckBox  Name="checkModules" Content="{Binding}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}",
                           CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Sir,I have umcommented it while running and changed the it to CheckCommand but still it is  not working....Even if the checkbox is checked the brekpoint is not reaching there...

Comment: what exactly is not working? did the command fire? is your datacontext correctly setted?

Comment: the command did not fire...I'm confused regrading your datacontext point...In the xaml.cs i have uncommented this.datacontext=new viewmodel(); because it leads to infinite loop

Comment: Your user control have the UserModuleMappingViewModel  as DataContext? If yes, try to add a dummy event to your checkbox (like checked = "click") and in debug see if the DataContext of your checkbox still point to your viewModel

Comment: I edited my answer. Try using DataContext.CheckCommand where you take the datacontext from your listbox

Comment: Dan Sir,Imade a mistake in calling the view model but even after that the breakpoint didnt stopped at check command..I hope you got my query,i want the saved database values get checked on combobox change

Comment: DId you try my last edit? use   Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}. If ListBox doesn't have the correct viewmodel won't work

Comment: I tried but still it is not reaching the breakpoint...I am very thankul for your efforts

Comment: I cannot replicate your Code. I'm pretty sure you are messing with your DataContext. Check which is the closest parent to your checkbox that has your viewmodel as DataContext, and try to put as Ancestor in your command binding

Comment: Dan,I did as you said but i didn't get the solution....will you provide me any other solution

Comment: If you don't provide me any other detail i can't help you sorry

Comment: Will you provide me your email id so that i can share you the demo project